# NestJS Mongoose how to update different schemas that have a relationship with a single call

Tags: mongoose, orm, nestjs, relationship

In my NestJS app I am using Mongoose.
I have two schemas: `Animals` and `Mammals`. `Animals` has a property `mammals` that collects the `uuids` of the `Mammals`.
How can I create a relationship between these two entities such that when posting a new `Mammal`, the "Animals.mammals" array will be updated with a single call?

At the moment I have a situation like this:

```
@Schema({ timestamps: true })
export class Animal {
    // Referencing to a custom uuid
    @Prop({ type: [Types.ObjectId], ref: Mammal.name + '.customUuid' })
    mammals: Mammal[]
}

@Schema({ timestamps: true })
export class Mammal{
    // Referencing to _id produced by mongo
    @Prop({ type: [Types.ObjectId], ref: Animal.name })
    animal: Animal
}
```

And when I have to create a new `Mammal` I can:

```
const newMammal = this.mammalModel.create(mammalObj);
const updatedAnimal = this.animalModel.findByIdAndUpdate(
 animalId, 
 { $push: { mammals: mammal.customUuid } }, 
 { new: true }
);
await Promise.all([newMammal, updatedAnimal]);
```

I wonder if there is a way to establish a relationship that will automatically `$push` a new value in the `Animal` that corresponds to the id passed in the `mammalModel.create`.